# Как из даты,которую ввёл пользователь,отнять текущую дату?

Tags: haskell

Вот код

```
 getDateFromUser :: IO (Either UserError Date)
 getDateFromUser = do
     Prelude.putStrLn "Пожалуйста, укажите дату для прогноза в формате    ГГГГ-ММ-ДД:"
     date <- Prelude.getLine
     currentTime <- getCurrentTime
     let forecastDay = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale "%Y-%m-%d" date :: Maybe Day
     if date >= ...
        then return $ Right $ (Data.Text.pack date)
        else return $ Left InvalidDate
```

Задача такова: я должен сравнить две даты (date - от пользователя,и текущую дату currentTime)
Брать дату от пользователя и отнимать текущую дату - и получаю разницу в днях.И эта разница должна быть не более чем 16
То есть дата от пользователя должна быть не раньше текущей (чтобы не улететь в прошлое), но не позже чем "текущая + 16 дней"

Answer (score 1):

Используйте функцию `diffDays` из модуля `Data.Time`: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.4.2/docs/Data-Time-Calendar.html#v%3AdiffDays